# parent process that calls waitpid() is unable to find its child

Tags: c

I am trying to better understand fork(), waitpid() and child/parent processes, however there are some strange behaviors I have encountered with the following code:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void){ // Main

    int status;
    pid_t wPID, cPID;
    printf("[%i] Hi I am the parent and I am about to create a child...\n", getpid());
    fflush(0); 
    pid_t childPID = fork();

    if (childPID >= 0){
        if(childPID == 0){ //child process
            cPID = getpid();
            printf("[%i] %i\n", getpid(), cPID );
            printf("[%i] Hi, I am the child process...\n", getpid() );
            sleep(1);

            for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
                printf("[%i] %i\n", getpid(), i);
            }
            exit(0);
        }
        else{ //parent
            printf("[%i] %i\n", getpid(), cPID );
            wPID = waitpid(cPID, &status, 0);
            printf("[%i] value returned by waitpid: %i\n", getpid(), wPID);

            if (WIFEXITED(status))
                printf("[%i] child exited, status=%d\n", getpid(), WEXITSTATUS(status));
            else if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
                printf("[%i] child killed (signal %d)\n", getpid(), WTERMSIG(status));
            else if (WIFSTOPPED(status))
                printf("[%i] child stopped (signal %d)\n", getpid(), WSTOPSIG(status));
            else  /* Non-standard case -- may never happen */
                printf("Unexpected status (0x%x)\n", status);
            return 0; 
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("\n Fork failed, quitting!\n");
        return 2;  // error
    }
}
```

console output:

```
$ ./waitpidexample 
[6103] Hi I am the parent and I am about to create a child...
Error: No child processes
[6103] 1540418008
[6103] value returned by waitpid: -1
[6103] child killed (signal 54)
[6104] 6285
[6104] Hi, I am the child process...
[6104] 0
[6104] 1
[6104] 2
```

I believe my issue is in the cPID variable being used in waitpid()...

there is some sort of scope issue happening here, as it evaluates to different values in the child / parent.

How am I supposed to get the correct child process id for use in waitpid()?

Why is the code after my waitpid() being executed before the code in the child process?

Comment: The child PID is in `childPID`, not `cPID`...

Comment: The output you show doesn't match the program you show. There's nowhere in the program where you print `Error: No child processes`. Although that could be because of the *undefined behavior* you have when doing `fflush` with a null pointer.

Comment: Also, when a function like `waitpid` returns with an error (in the case of many system functions indicated by a return of `-1`) then you need to check [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) to figure out what happened. And you need to do it immediately, you can't call any function which might alter `errno` in between.

Comment: Lastly, and what seems to be your misunderstanding, is that when a process forks a child process, the memory of the parent is *copied* into the child. Once that is done the memory of the parent and child are separate, there's no sharing at all. If you want to share memory, then either use *shared memory*, or use threads.

Comment: you are right I threw a perror("Error") there to see what I was getting but didnt put that up on the stack overflow code here. It wont let me edit it anymore but its not a huge issue.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!   IT is missing the two statements: `#include <sys/types.h>` and `#include <sys/wait.h>` which contains the definitions and prototypes for the function: `waitpid()`.   for these two statements: `printf("[%i] %i\n", getpid(), cPID );
            wPID = waitpid(cPID, &status, 0);`  the variable `cPID` has not been initialized.  Those two statements should have used the value returned from that call to `fork()`  I.E. `childPID`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cPID` is only changed in the child process. When you call fork, a complete copy is made (functionally, in reality until something is changed, the memory is shared). This means that when `cPID` is written in the child (first branch) the parent does not see it. Change the references to `cPID` in the parent (second branch) to `childPID` (assigned from `fork()`):

```
else{ //parent
    printf("[%i] %i\n", getpid(), childPID );
    wPID = waitpid(childPID, &status, 0);
    printf("[%i] value returned by waitpid: %i\n", getpid(), wPID);
    if (WIFEXITED(status))
        printf("[%i] child exited, status=%d\n", getpid(), WEXITSTATUS(status));
    else if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
        printf("[%i] child killed (signal %d)\n", getpid(), WTERMSIG(status));
    else if (WIFSTOPPED(status))
        printf("[%i] child stopped (signal %d)\n", getpid(), WSTOPSIG(status));
    else  /* Non-standard case -- may never happen */
        printf("Unexpected status (0x%x)\n", status);
        return 0;
}
```

Also, I recommend using braces after all your `if` statements

#### Run Order

`fork()` does not define which process gets run first, just that there is now a child process (in which it returns 0) and a parent process (in which it returns the child's PID). The child process will be identical to the parent, except for the return value of `fork()`. Sometimes, the parent goes first, sometimes the child does. It is non-deterministic.

Answer (score 2):

In the parent process, `cPID` is never initialized.  The variables in the parent and child are separate from each other, so a variable change in the child is not visible in the parent and vice versa.

The parent already has the child pid in `childPID`, so use that instead.

```
printf("[%i] %i\n", getpid(), childPID );
wPID = waitpid(childPID, &status, 0);
```